# XBee S2 stops sending after it receives a packet

Tags: crash, serial-port, beagleboneblack, xbee

I have a two XBee-network. The first one is connected to a [BeagleBone Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black) and the second one is connected to my PC.

The BeagleBone Black is sending sensor values to the PC regularly, 10 times a second, etc. But when I send a command to the BeagleBone Black from my PC, the BeagleBone Black stops sending messages.

1. The BeagleBone Black can send or receive successfully (separately). The error occurs only after receive. And even after error occurs, the BeagleBone Black can still receive. It just can't send.
2. After the error occurs, when I restart the BeagleBone Black program, the problem is solved. But if I restart the PC program, the problem continues. Therefore problem is on the BeagleBone Black.

I checked everything, but I couldn't find the problem.

Note: XBees work in API Mode.

Comment: Show us some code?  Or are you just using a terminal emulator?  Could hardware flowcontrol (RTS/CTS) be blocking transmissions?

Comment: I found the problem. The problem is in BBB. To test the system first  i connected two different XBees to same UART. (One for receiving, one for sending) . Problem did not get solved. Right now i use two different XBees on two different UARTs. I dont have enough time to investigate problem further. Therefore i will keep going with tow XBees

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not share your code, I'll share two solutions that come to mind:

1- The communication range of the XBee module is too much. Ten data may be a little low at the moment. Send more data.

2- You have incorrectly configured send and receive actions in your code. If you do not release the serial port after the data from the serial port is complete, you may have stuck in the read mode.

If you share your code, it will be incomplete or the problem will appear more easily.